# screen disable "detached" message

Tags: python, gnu-screen

I'm using screen to manage multiple "screens" with usage of some python scripts. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/Christophe31/screenutils) to manage screen using python code.

How to disable the output:

```
[remote detached from 52689.demo_session]
[52689.demo_session detached.]
```

I get each time using the library?
I already created a .screenrc file inside the home dir of the user running the script containing:

```
msgwait 0
startup_message off
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the output going? If it's in the console you can try

```
import sys
import os

sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
use_your_library()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```